# android sql getContact by name first character

Tags: android, sql, listview

i have SQL database

Contain column :

ID - Name - Price - Category - Count - Color - First_Litter

Example :

1 - Test1 - 10 - Test1 - 0 - Yellow - T

2 - Test2 - 12 - Test2 - 2 - Red    - T

3 - Test3 - 15 - Test3 - 7 - Green  - T

4 - Cast1 - 15 - Cast1 - 5 - Blue   - C

i want to get this contact using the First_Litter
i have this code which get item item by ID and working fine

```
    public Items getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_PRICE, KEY_CATEGORY,KEY_COUNT,KEY_BGC,KEY_FL }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Items contact = new Items(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6));
    // return contact
    return contact;
}
```

i edited this code a little bit to getContact by First Litter

```
    public Items getContactFL(String fl) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                KEY_NAME, KEY_PRICE, KEY_CATEGORY,KEY_COUNT,KEY_BGC,KEY_FL }, KEY_FL + "=?",
                new String[] { fl }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Items contact = new Items(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6));
        // return contact
        return contact;
    }
```

but its not working, it only give me 1 item

i need when i do getContactFL("A") , show me all Items have A in column FirstLitter

can someone help me and sorry for my bad english

Comment: use `LEFT(colName, 1)` for selecting the first character of the column using **SQL(db.rawQuery)**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i don't think you column for first_letter.... you can use like to do so...

```
String Query="SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_CONTACTS+" WHERE "+KEY_NAME+" LIKE '%"+f1+"%'";
Cursor Cursor=db.rawQuery(Query, null);
```

ok change the code

```
if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Items contact = new Items(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6));
    // return contact
    return contact;
```

to

```
Items[] contact=new Items[cursor.getCount()];
int i=0;cursor.moveToFirst();
while (!cursor.isAfterLast())
{
    contact[i++] = new Items(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6));
    cursor.moveToNext();
}
    return contact;
```

Comment: NAME in Capital Litters  is Column name right?
fl is First litter?
  what about the small litters "name"

Comment: ok sorry i've updated the answer...... and f1 is the parameter passed to function getContactFL()

Comment: ok i tried getContactFL("A") but same result it only show  the same First Item that Contain ("A") multiple time

Comment: .CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 8 requested, with a size of 8  i get that error

Comment: ok @SamAyoub95 ... i'm messing something with the cursor...i've updated the answer once again...check this...

Comment: it works i used   Log.e("",cursor.getString(1)); to see the item names and it works.. but what i'm trying to do is to add this values to expendable listview  ,,,  in public Object getChild i use  return db.getContact(childPosition); its show all items,  but when i do db.getContactFL(GroupName); it give me  Index 8 requested, with a size of 8 i get that erro

Answer (score -1):

try like this,may help you 
    public Items getContactFL(String fl) {

```
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                KEY_NAME, KEY_PRICE, KEY_CATEGORY,KEY_COUNT,KEY_BGC,KEY_FL }, KEY_FL + "=?",
                new String[] { fl }, null, null, null, null);

 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                  //put your item code here
 }

 if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
  }

    // return contact
    return contact;
}
```